# Rail3 | How to create standard route/action for ALL controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Well, DRY! So i thought it should be easy to add a new action (like the existing new, edit) to all my controllers (in my case copy). But how do you setup a new route for ALL controllers?

*Without going in to 'loops' (i.e. %w().each ...) inside the routes.rb ?*

I mean, we want DRY right? So you don't want copy your action inside the routes file for each resource. I guess you should be able to extend the default actions/routes (index, new, edit,etc.) easy?

Thanks!

Comment: -1 for what? whats wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0):

AFIK no way to do this by default.  You could monkey-patch resources to include this functionality:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b229bc70e50ec0887c5bb3aaaa9c6ee8af054026/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L982

...but my hunch is you would be better off re-considering whether this functionality can be created another way, since what you want to do is "off the Rails".

One option is create a CloneController#new that accepts a model and id and creates a clone.  This seems like it would be drier, and wouldn't require you to pepper a gazillion "clone_article" "clone_blog" "clone_user" paths all over the place.

Obviously you would want to carefully white-list the models/ids that can be passed in.

Comment: yes i know. But i need to add a route 'clone' for all my controllers. So you get: /company/1/clone  /people/23/clone  etc.

Comment: Ahh misread, thought you wanted to create a 'new' action, editing answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source there isn't a way to add to the default actions for a resource.

But, as @juwiley says, the methods `resources :item` is just a shortcut for creating a load of `member` and `collection` methods.

All you need to do is something like this

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper

  def resources_with_copy(*resources, &block)

    block_with_copy = lambda do
      block.call

      member do
        post :copy
      end
    end

    resources(*resources, &block_with_copy)
  end
end
```

Then in your routes.rb just say

```
resources_with_copy :items
resources_with_copy :posts do
  member do
    post :share
  end
end
...
```